# cURL POST & GET command not working

Tags: curl

I am trying to apply the cURL command on this website: http://surework.com/postalcode.html

This is my cURL that I am applying:

```
curl --data "address=658071&button=Find" http://surework.com/postalcode.html
```

But it is not working.

May I know where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Please try to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replicate form submit with your curl command, than it won't work to the page you mentioned. This page intercepts form submit with javascript, so form submission doesn't reach server at all.
Unless you can add POST requests processing to the server side code, you won't be able to get expected results on this website from your curl command.

However, if you just need a result similar to what you show on a page, you may curl `http://gothere.sg/maps/geo` directly instead of surework.com.

Comment: Is there other alternative besides using curl? or can I modify the existing the contents of postalcode.html file to make curl command working?

Comment: It's not the page, who's responsible for curl response it's a webserver. You need to add piece of code, which will respond to your POST request. Another option may be to call `http://gothere.sg/maps/geo` instead of surework, like it's done in js on the page. I've updated the answer with this.